# django/jquery - how do you mingle jquery template tags with django template tags without conflicts

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-views, jquery-templates

How do I use django templates tags with jquery template tags ([link](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/)) without creating any conflicts? Both use {{ }} for marking tags. Does Django 1.3 have something to deal with this kind of issue? Real examples would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the kinds of conflicts you're having problems with? Are you trying to include a copy of jQuery within the admin site?

Comment: @Alo For example I would like to add something like this: $('#some_id').val('{{ someid }}'); . From what I know and from what I've tried the '{{' for the django template tag creates a conflict with jquery/javascript.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have variable called "someid" which is passed to the template, it will work out just fine. What conflicts are you encountering? There really shouldn't be any.

Comment: @cheshire Sorry, I should have been more specific. The problem is that if you are trying to use jquery template tags ( see: http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/ ) they look the same like the django template tags {{ }}.

Comment: Just edited the question to eliminate any confusion. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in solutions in django that can help with this somewhat are

The [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) tag with:

```
{% templatetag openvariable %}
{% templatetag closevariable %}
```

Whenever you need to use {{ or }} in your javascript which unfortunately will severely impact the readability of your code.

Alternatively if your javascript is static, then putting it in a separate file and including it with [{% ssi %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ssi) without parsing it as a template would prevent conflicts.

There's no really clean way to escape template tags in django templates that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Use or write a templatetag that just leaves what is inside as it is. You can find an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/629508).

```
{% verbatim %}
... your js code including {{templates}}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: this was added to django in v1.5. you can also grab it from codebase and add as template tag to your own project. https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/template/defaulttags.py#L453